# Zero credibility factor

Tags: bayesian

Let's suppose that $X|\theta \sim N(\mu, \frac{1}{\theta})$, where $\mu$ known and $\Theta \sim Gamma(a,b)$ where $a,b>0$ known parameters. I want to compute the credibility factor $Ζ=\frac{n}{n+k}$ where $n$ is the length of the data and $k=\frac{E_{\Theta}[Var(X|\Theta)]  }{  Var_{\Theta}[E(X|\Theta)] }$.But the   denominator is $ Var_{\Theta}[E(X|\Theta)] =  Var_{\Theta}[\mu] = 0$, which means that $k=\infty$ and $Z=0$. What exactly does this mean?  Is it feasible?

Comment: So you are assuming at the same time that $\mu$ is a random variable and that it has zero variance?

Comment: I assume that $\mu$ is a known number. So, the variance of a number is zero.

Comment: Do known numbers have variances?

Comment: This is the main problem.. That known numbers do not have variances.

Comment: You might want to explain where the credibility factor comes from. It doesn't seem to correspond to the [wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credibility_theory#Actuarial_credibility) which requires two different samples.

Answer (score 0):

Credibility factor(Z) is weighting  factor on  data from risk itself, and (1-Z) weight on complement data(it is external information for the same risk).

Now, you have variance from your complement data as 0, that is other information is statistically correct, no need for weightage-average. The expected-risk should be mean(complement data), so Z=0.